# Does postgres support explicitly typed arrays?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Does postgres support the following?

```
SELECT ARRAY<INT64>[1,2];
```

Instead of just:

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,2]
```

[image]

---

As an example from BigQuery of what I mean:

[image]

Or is the only way to cast it after declaring a literal, such as:

```
select ARRAY[1,2]::int[];
```

Comment: What happend when you tried? https://dbfiddle.uk/Ho4tsJ0s

Comment: @FrankHeikens added to question.

Comment: Well, that's pretty clear, it's not valid syntax for PostgreSQL

Comment: @FrankHeikens sure, my question is if there is any way to specify the array type in Postgres? Is the answer that it's not and only via a cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> specify the array type in Postgres

Manual **8.15.1. Declaration of Array Types**
when you create an table, you can declare the array type. The following is  manual example.

```
CREATE TABLE sal_emp (
    name            text,
    pay_by_quarter  integer[],
    schedule        text[][]
);
```

When you do a select then you need cast. Because it will be resolved to a certain type. Then you can cast to the type you want.

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3], pg_typeof(ARRAY[1,2,3])
union
SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3]::smallint[], pg_typeof(ARRAY[1,2,3])
union
SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3]::bigint[], pg_typeof(ARRAY[1,2,3])
union all
SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3]::[numeric], pg_typeof(ARRAY[1,2,3]);
```

Quote from manual:

> By default, the array element type is the common type of the member
> expressions, determined using the same rules as for UNION or CASE
> constructs.